# Use Auto-Layout with UIPresentationController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uikit, uiviewanimationtransition, uipresentationcontroller

I'm subclassing `UIPresentationController` to create a custom presentation/transition of a pop up `UIViewController`.  The popup view itself should be constrained in the frame of the presenting view controller.  I could do it with manual frame calculations but it would be greatly tedious and error prone in my view.

Looking at the API for `UIPresentationController` it looks like it strongly enforces the usage of `CGSize`'s and `CGRect`'s and insists on making you mix and match 'quasi auto layout' methods like `systemlayoutSizeFitting` and others and is just altogether confusing.  I don't know which methods need to be overridden, when views exists, when they are added, which overrides return values are prioritized over other return values.  Its basically a nightmare.

What, if any, is the simplest way to use the conventional constraint based layout I'm use to in this API?

Comment: In the same situation, I wanted presentation controller for a background view so it was pretty simple. I didn’t override  frame functions. I have used the presentation controller minimally and used the animator with auto layout.